# How to listen for a process start event from my windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want my Windows service to be able to listen for when a particular process, process A, for example, runs and be able to shut it down at will. How possible is this?

Comment: [GetProcessByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8), [Kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.8). If it has a window interface, you can [CloseMainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=netframework-4.8) (that's like clicking the "X")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ManagementEventWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventwatcher) class to receive a notification when a process is started.

> Subscribes to temporary event notifications based on a specified event query.

There is an example on the MSDN page which might fit your needs.

> The following example shows how the client receives notification when an instance of Win32_Process is created because the event class is __InstanceCreationEvent.

The `ManagementEventWatcher` class allows you to set a [WqlEventQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.wqleventquery) to specify the type of WQL event to listen for.  More information on WQL query options and structure are available in the [WQL (SQL for WMI) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) and [WMI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-reference).

Alternatively, you can query an array of running processes returned by [Process.GetProcesses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses) at an interval using a timer.

Then, get a reference to the process using [Process.GetProcessByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname) or directly from the resulting array returned by [Process.GetProcesses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses) and use the [Process.Kill()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill) method to kill the process.

Comment: Thanks! Process.GetProcessesByName() worked for me. Although I had to simulate a little delay in the onStart of my Service.

Comment: I'm unclear about how to actually listen for the event of a particular process starting. For example, if notepad.exe starts how do i notify my event of that?

Comment: @BenKay Use the `WaitForNextEvent()` method to listen for the event.  If you're referring to the code in the example, be aware that they have set a timeout for 5 seconds, so you might like to remove or extend the timeout or use a loop.  The event that is being listened for in the example is the start of _any_ Win32 process, so once you receive the event you can call and enumerate the result from `GetProcesses()` to find the process you are looking for.  If it's not there, just loop and `WaitForNextEvent()` again.

Comment: @BenKay the service `onStart()` method should finish without delay.  You might prefer to start a `Task` or `Thread` to continue work instead.